# MoveIt Colcon build can't finish installing, because it uses the entire RAM and crashes Ubuntu

Tags: build, ubuntu-20.04, ros2, moveit, colcon

To move a robotic arm (UR5e) I am instructed to use ROS2 Galactic and MoveIt in Ubuntu 20.04 Debian.
I followed the instructions given in the [MoveIt Documentation](https://moveit.picknik.ai/galactic/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html) up until

```
colcon build --mixin release
```

The command itself isn't the problem*[1], it just keeps on devouring my CPU and RAM. In the last three days I managed to deal with the CPU, but I can't seem to be able to limit the RAM & SWAP.

So I manage to get to **37/45** completed. But that's when the RAM and SWAP are at 100% and the system freezes.

*[1] on 37/45 completed I get the following:

```
Failed   <<< pilz_industrial_motion_planner
```

With my endless tries to get this under control, I modified the command to

```
systemd-run --scope -p MemoryLimit=3000M -p CPUQuota=70% -- colcon build --mixin release --parallel-workers 3
```

I tried <kbd>cpulimit</kbd>, but an Ubuntu extension to manage the output works right now.
The combination <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> stops the process and continues by typing <kbd>fg</kbd> without complications. But that just keeps the RAM at that percentage.

I also played with <kbd>swappiness</kbd>, <kbd>ulimit</kbd> and <kbd>nice</kbd>, but I haven't noticed a difference.

Comment: did you try with --parallel-workers 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `—-executor sequential` to the Colvin command. This will build one package at a time. Optionally you can also add `--allow-overriding` which will override packages that are already built in